# Conditionally triggering slide and hide javascript events

Tags: javascript

I added some hide and slide functions to a website so that as each product attribute was selected the next one would slide out. This worked fine until the customer added additional attributes to SOME products. The additional attribute is causing me problems because i can't add a second slide function trigger without making it trigger two functions on these products.

The original code i used is

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').hide();

$('.sizeRadio').click(function () {
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').slideDown(800);
});
```

The client then added an attribute id4 so i added

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions4').change(function () {
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').slideDown(800);
});
```

But this means that on pages where BOTH attributes are in use option11 is sliding down when .sizeRadio is clicked and not when option4 is changed.

In short, is it possible to make it function so that if .wrapperAttribsOptions4 is present then

```
$('.sizeRadio').click(function () {
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').slideDown(800);
});
```

is ignored.

I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: any jsfiddle with running demo?

Comment: @gp fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/pkBbb/
You will see that when you select the size option both the Product Centre and Engraving requirements options slide out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using

```
if ($('.wrapperAttribsOptions4').length != 0) {
```

so the whole code segment becomes

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').hide();
if ($('.wrapperAttribsOptions4').length != 0) {
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions4').change(function () {
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').slideDown(800);
});
}else
$('.sizeRadio').click(function () {
    $('.wrapperAttribsOptions11').slideDown(800);
});
```